# How to auto mount drive after every reboot

Tags: centos, mount, automounting

I am using centos 7 64 and i have a drive `/dev/vdb` and i am want to mount it to `/home` on every reboot.

I have tried to do it by add below lines on /etc/fstab

```
/dev/vdb /home auto  defaults,nobootwait,errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

But after doing this stoped booting so now i have removed it anyway

So please help me

Comment: It may be better to use the actual filesystem type (instead of `auto`).  You can find that with `file -s /dev/vdb`

Comment: Also, you want to mount it as a subdirectory of home (I am guessing) like /home/user/mountpoint, otherwise, it will mount over /home and you won't be able to access your home directory (unless that is what you want)